# Getting file in subfolder of same directory

Tags: php, html, directory-structure, subdirectory

I have a structure like this:

```
currentFolder
    currentFile.php
    email
        email.php
```

I'm in the file `currentFile.php` and need to include the `email.php` file.

I've tried to include `email/email.php` and include `/email/email.php` but neither will work?

What's the actual url to include this `email.php` into `currentFile.php`?

Answer (score 0):

You need enclose your strings with either single or double quote marks. Like so:

```
include 'email/email.php';
```

If your string begins with a `/` chatracter, PHP will only look from the root of the filesystem. (Instead of relative to your current file)

So `include '/email/email.php';` will look here:

```
/email/email.php
```

And `include 'email/email.php';` will look here:

```
/currentFolder/email/email.php
```

Comment: Sorry, I did wrap them in a string but when I'm echoing the contents of that include it is not working.

Ex: $test = include 'email/email.php'; and then I'll print_r($test); die(); and it's null? The Email.php file contains html and PHP within it.

Comment: That is beyond the scope of this question. But simply put you can't echo something and it be returned by the file. (echo always prints to the page) But I would start by reading [this page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) from top-to-bottom and checkout [W3 Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/php/) PHP tutorials.

Comment: Also, `die()` and `exit()` will kill all the current PHP running. This applies to your file that you are including from.

Answer (score 0):

Use constant **DIR** to know the directory located the current file.

include **DIR**.'/email/email.php

Answer (score 0):

Better use `__DIR__` on this case. Try this:

```
require_once __DIR__ . "\email\email.php"
```

But only works on PHP 5.3 <